# How to resolve a NA/NaN/Inf execution halted error?

Tags: r, function, syntax-error

> Quitting from lines 12-26 (6,4-PresentationRMARKDOWN.Rmd)  Error in
> do_one(nmeth) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1) Calls:
>  ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval ->
> kmeans -> do_one
>
> Execution halted

```
pwvspl <- function(dataselected){
  dataselected <- iris
  data(dataselected)
  set.seed(8593)
  dataselected
  dataselected$species <- NULL
  (kmeans.result <- kmeans(dataselected,3))
  table(dataselected$Species, kmeans.result$cluster)
  plot(dataselected[c("Petal.Length","Petal.Width")], col = kmeans.result$cluster)
  points(kmeans.result$centers[c("Petal.Length","Petal.Width")],col=1:3, pch=3, cex=2)
  data(dataselected)
  data_for_clustering <-dataselected[,-5]
  clusters_dataselected <- kmeans(data_for_clustering, centers=3)
  plotcluster(data_for_clustering,clusters_dataselected$cluster)
  clusplot(data_for_clustering,clusters_dataselected$cluster, color=TRUE, shade=TRUE, main = "Petal Width vs. Petal Length", xlab="Petal Length", ylab="Petal Width")
}
```

I am unsure what is causing this error. How do I resolve this error?

Comment: dig into your code and try to localize the point where it happens.  Try `traceback()` and `debug()`. My guess is that the problem occurs because you have a non-numeric variable in your data set (`iris`).

Comment: @BenBolker I have checked my dataset for a non-numeric value and I have set that to null. ```{r}dataselected$Species <- NULL```  however I am still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `dataselected$species <- NULL` change this line to just converting the species factors to numeric:

```
dataselected$Species <- as.numeric(dataselected$Species)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

The traceback shows

```
3. do_one(nmeth) 
2. kmeans(dataselected, 3) 
1. pwvspl()
```

which means the error is inside the `kmeans` function. To be precise, the error is in function `do_one`, which is called by `kmeans`.

The help page for `kmeans` says

> numeric matrix of data, or an object that can be coerced to such a matrix (such as a numeric vector or a data frame with all numeric columns).

But the `iris` dataframe has nonnumeric columns (whose values become `NA` when the function tries to coerce them to numeric).

That's the cause of the error.

Comment: how do I fix this? i have set my non-numeric values to null

Comment: Now you're getting a new error, which comes from the call to `table`. From this point on, you must think about what you want to do with the results of `kmeans`